# Angular 5 nouislider with two inputs

Tags: angular, nouislider

I want to achieve below behavior on one of my personal projects which is written in angular 5. A slider which will have a specific range based on the data from a service. I tried to search a lot but couldn't find proper example which gives me a start point. Has anyone implemented such behavior in angular 5. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with **[`ng2-nouislider`](http://tb.github.io/ng2-nouislider/)** and i have implemented in project as well.

You just need to provide the range in config as follows,

```
someRange2config: any = {
  behaviour: 'drag',
  connect: true,
  margin: 1,
  limit: 5, // NOTE: overwritten by [limit]="10"
  range: {
    min: 0,
    max: 20
  },
  pips: {
    mode: 'steps',
    density: 5
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. Also how to get the two inputs. Changing the input values manually should also drag the slider to the desired position.

Comment: just add two inputs with ngModel , and bind those values to the range on ngModelchange. mark if the answer helped